# How to hide SqlExceptionHelper warnings

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have the following method:

```
public String methodName(Entity instance) {
   try {
      repository.delete(instance);
      return "Instance was deleted !";
   } catch (Exception e) {
      return "Instance cannot be deleted !";
   }
}
```

I thought that catching the Exception inside `try/catch` won't output anything on the console, but it prints this:

`o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint.`

Is there any way I can prevent this warning from showing up on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding try/catch will not prevent the exception being thrown. It only prevent from interrupting your application flow by an exception.

The logs you can see on the console are hard-coded somewhere in JPA library and - to be honest - a very helpful to understand why something went wrong.

If you really want to block the logging on the console you a free to do it. Usually it can be done with a configuration file logback.xml You can provide package names and log levels for the console and/or log files.

It would be too long story for this answer to describe how to do it.

Comment: Well given these circumstances I'd rather change the way I'm deleting instances than fiddling with the internals of JPA. Thank you for the explanation.